# web2py cannot import pymysql 0.9.2 : No module named cryptography.hazmat.backends

Tags: cryptography, web2py, pymysql

I installed web2py in Windows using web2py.exe. When I try to update pymysql using 0.9.2, I got this error "No module named cryptography.hazmat.backends" when I try to start web2py.exe and cannot import pymysql driver. This only happens with pymysql 0.9.2 not 0.8.1 or lower. pymysql 0.9.2 works ok on windows alone not with web2py. I know that for pymysql 0.9.2 it requires cryptography, I already installed it via pip3. May I ask what I'm missing? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows binary version of web2py (i.e., web2py.exe) includes its own Python interpreter and does not use the system installed Python or any of its libraries. External libraries must be installed into its `/site-packages` folder. However, given that you already have Python installed on your system, a simpler option is to use the source version of web2py rather than web2py.exe.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. Using source code works. May I ask how to install the external libraries into /site-packages? I used pip install cryptography --target=my_web2py_exe_version_dir\site-packages, but after install, it still gives the same error